# Alternatives to Fokker Planck formalism

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

The problem setting is quite general and as follows:

An infinite number of particles (probability density) is moving in 1d space, with force defined at each point by function *F*. It also undergoes diffusion by Brownian noise *W*. All boundary conditions are defined properly.

Are there approaches to find the distribution beyond Fokker Planck/forward Kolmogorov equations?

These may be however advanced, because the motivation is not the solution (that can be extracted directly with FP) but aggregation of tools.